# Grunticon For Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svg, fonts

Is there an equivalent to Grunticon for Rails?

Whilst researching SVG images vs fonts for dynamically coloured images, I found [Grunticon](https://github.com/filamentgroup/grunticon) which seems to manage the trade-offs quite elegantly with fallback to png.

But I'm using RoR and this is based on node.js so unless I'm misinformed, it isn't going to work me.

So does anyone know of a similar type of service of approach for elegantly handling dynamically customizable images in rails?

p.s. I'm using a font-based approach at the moment.